# Average causal effect of one year increase in schooling vs a four-year increase in schooling

Tags: causality, conditional-expectation

I'm not sure why in *Mostly Harmless Econometrics*, [last paragraph of p. 55](http://books.google.com/books?id=ztXL21Xd8v8C&lpg=PA55&vq=average%20causal%20effect%20of%20a%20one%20year&pg=PA55#v=onepage&q&f=false), the expectations of $f_{i}(s-4)$ is taken and the expectation of $f_{i}(s-1)$ is not. The text reads:

> Conditional on $X_{i}$, the *average causal effect* of one-year increase in schooling is $E[f_{i}(s)-f_{i}(s-1) \vert X_{i}]$, while the average causal effect of a four-year increase in schooling is $E[f_{i}(s)-E[f_{i}(s-4)] \vert X_{i}]$

In the second equation there is an expectation inside the expectation.

Comment: The [corrections section](http://www.mostlyharmlesseconometrics.com/tag/corrections/) of the MHE site does seem to include this.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov, useful link, but I didn't find a post about this. Not even in the second page. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I left out the "not" in that sentence. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news, I guess. This is a typo. Sent an email to the [site](http://www.mostlyharmlesseconometrics.com/tag/corrections/) @DimitriyV.Masterov cited and got a reply sooner than I would expect. [Here is the answer post](http://www.mostlyharmlesseconometrics.com/2014/02/whoops/).